# Check whether a banner is viewed for a period of time using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript.
In my application I want to check whether a banner that is displayed in the browser is viewed by the user for a period of time.
It can be informed by giving an alert message.
I have tried, with success, different methods to solve this problem.

Here is the code I used to display the page load time.
How can I adapt this to solve my problem?

```js
var beforeload = new Date().getTime();
window.onload = gettimeload;

function gettimeload() {
    var aftrload = new Date().getTime();
    // Time calculating in seconds
    time = (aftrload - beforeload) / 1000;
    document.getElementById("lbltxt").outerHTML = "Your Page took <font color='red'><b>" + time + "</b></font> Seconds to Load";

}
// var quoteElement = document.getElementById("get").innerHTML="iFrame";
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="lbltxt">Test</div>
</body>
```

Comment: So what is the goal here? You want to switch banners within a certain amount of time?

Comment: No need to switch the banners... I want to get an alert message that after page loads wait for a period of time [On waiting time the user may use scroll bars or go back to another tab etc and alert a message that the banner is displayed to the  client.